# Members upload photos into their own subdirectory?

Tags: safecracker, uploads

We are working on a site with 350 or so businesses. They are able to upload 5 photos and a logo to their front-end profile. It would be nice (for organization-sake) if they could upload images into their own subdirectory. "/images/members/{member_name}/image.jpg"

Is there any way to achieve this? less manually creating 350 upload directories...

Currently using P&T Assets.

Comment: I'm curious to see if anyone suggests building out an extension for this and which hook they would suggest using. I think you'd probably need to elaborate on which member mod you are using and how they are able to upload their photos &  logo.

Comment: We are using Profile:Edit.

Comment: Dan, what did you end up using as a solution for this?

Comment: We ended up using channel images, which creates a subdirectory per entry. However, we couldnt get the functionality of giving the directory a custom name or name based on entry title. So the path would be "images/member-uploads/{entry_id}/imageName.jpg"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a member is a channel entry (or tied to a channel entry) and you are open to using an add-on other than Assets, then [Channel Images](http://www.devdemon.com/channel_images/) would be a good route. It automatically creates a separate upload subdirectory per entry. *But* it uses `entry_id` for the name of the subdirectory, so wouldn't quite be the setup you wanted for the subdirectory name.

Comment: We did this on http://instaar.colorado.edu for all the people profiles and basically, in the field instructions atop the Safecracker form they use to edit their profile, told them what folder to look in for their uploaded images. Works fine. http://cl.ly/image/2u3n002D2S2X

Comment: Nice site Chad. Im just north of Boulder. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Brandon of P&T put out [this extension](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/wygwam_upload_tags) for Wygwam a while back. It could be a place to start looking for appropriate hooks to accomplish this.